Probability of Coffee being Hotter than some Temperature?
My cousin and I have been long debating this question: Will a cafe with fresh but inferior quality coffee beans have "better coffee?" compared to a cafe with superior quality coffee beans but brews coffee less frequently?
This of course is a subjective and open ended question - but I tried to use my mathematical creativity to make a related math problem.

Suppose there is a cafe with one employee. The cafe opens in the morning at time=0

At time=0, the employee brews  a 1 liter pot of coffee that takes 1 minute to brew.

When the coffee is ready, it is $x$ degrees C and cools down each minute to a minimum of $y$ degrees C  (room temperature) according to some function $G(t)$

As soon as the cafe opens, customers start arriving randomly according to some Poisson Process, wait in line according to some process and served according to some process (after serving they leave). The queue can grow infinitely long. Customers are served in the order that they come in (First In First Out).

Each customer has a 1/3 chance of ordering 0 ml of coffee, 1/3 chance of 100 ml of coffee, 1/3 chance of ordering 200 ml of coffee. Suppose a customer orders 200 ml of coffee but there is only 100 ml left. The employee will toss out the remaining coffee and brew a fresh pot. No new orders are placed and no existing orders are completed while the coffee is being brewed.

Once the coffee is finished, the employee puts another pot on and waits for it to brew. During this time, more people can enter the line at this time.

The cafe closes at night when time=t. The current order is finished and all other customers are denied.


My Question: If a customer enters the cate at some given some initial conditions (e.g. current queue length, current coffee temperature in the pot, etc) ...what is the probability that this customer's cup of coffee will be less than t1 degrees Celsius?
I have no idea how to work on this problem - I tried to write down my thoughts in isolation

Coffee Temperature Model:
Let T(t) be the temperature of the coffee at time t. We can write (Where $k$ is the cooling rate constant.):

$$T(t) = y + (x-y)e^{-kt}$$

Customer Arrival Process:
Let $N(t)$ be the number of customers arriving up to time $t$. This follows a Poisson process with rate $λ$:

$$P(N(t) = n) = \frac{(λt)^n e^{-λt}}{n!}$$

Coffee Order Distribution:
Let $V$ be the volume of coffee ordered by a customer:

$$P(V = 0) = P(V = 100) = P(V = 200) = \frac{1}{3}$$

Queue Length:
Let $Q(t)$ be the queue length at time $t$. Such queues are often modelled birth-death process ($μ$ is the service rate):

$$\frac{dP_n(t)}{dt} = λP_{n-1}(t) + μP_{n+1}(t) - (λ+μ)P_n(t)$$

Coffee Volume in Pot:
Let $C(t)$ be the volume of coffee in the pot at time $t$ ($V_i$ is the volume ordered by the $i^{th}$ customer):

$$C(t) = 1000 - \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} V_i$$

Brewing Process:
Let $B(t)$ be a binary variable indicating if coffee is brewing at time $t$:

$$B(t) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } C(t) = 0 \text{ and } t \mod 1 < 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Probability of Coffee Temperature:
Let $P(T < t1 | Q=q, C=c, T=t0)$ be the probability that a customer's coffee is below $t_1$ degrees, given current queue length $q$, coffee volume $c$, and temperature $t_0$.

This probability depends on the time the customer will be served, which is influenced by the queue length and whether new coffee needs to be brewed. We can express this as:
$$P(T < t_1 | Q=q, C=c, T=t_0) =  ???$$
I don't know how to continue from here. How can I write the Probability Distribution for this problem? Is it even possible?

Suggestion: try solving it with specific values for all of the constants, then when you've gotten a better feel for the problem, you can go back and use parameters for them to get a more general answer.

For a random thought experiment, you have WAY too much complexity. Try doing the simplest possible thing (maybe coffee temp decreases linearly and people show up on an interval while you show up randomly) get an answer, and then try (one at a time) adding extra features to see how that effects the problem. Most complicating assumptions probably don’t matter much for your specific comparison (which depends on the values of your constants and observed behavior).
